# Azure Devops - How to use a powershell command to run SQL Scripts

Tags: sql, powershell, azure-devops

So, I am creating a build / deploy pipeline in azure Devops.

One issue I ran into is that I need to run a few SQL scripts every time a deploy is made. I am trying to do that through a Inline Powershell task.

The issue is that natively powershell does not recognize `Invoke-Sqlcmd`. So I had to install the module on the same script

I am doing that by doing

`Install-Module -Name SqlServer -AllowClobber -Scope CurrentUser -Force`

But any time it tries to run it is throwing me this error:

##[error]Exception calling "ShouldContinue" with "2" argument(s): "Windows PowerShell is in NonInteractive mode. Read and Prompt functionality is not available."

Answer (score 1):

I tried this:

```yaml
steps:
- task: PowerShell@2
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: 'Install-Module -Name SqlServer -Scope CurrentUser'

- task: PowerShell@2
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: 'Install-Module -Name SqlServer -AllowClobber -Scope CurrentUser -Force'
```

And for first I got `WARNING: User declined to install module (SqlServer)`, but second succeded. Can you show how exactly you call it in your pipeline?

Comment: `steps:
- task: petergroenewegen.PeterGroenewegen-Xpirit-Vsts-Build-InlinePowershell.Xpirit-Vsts-Build-InlinePowershell.InlinePowershell@1
  displayName: 'Inline Powershell'
  inputs:
    Script: |
     #Get Scripts Location
     Write-Host $(Agent.BuildDirectory)
     Set-Location $(Agent.BuildDirectory)
     
     Install-Module -Name SqlServer -AllowClobber -Scope CurrentUser -Force`

After that the script does its sql run thing

Answer (score 0):

Above error is because your self-hosted agent is running in service mode. I can reproduce the same error on my self-hosted agent which is configured Run as a service.

When i run my pipeline with above script on the self-hosted agent which is configured run interactively. It worked all fine.

You might need to reinstall your self-hosted agent and configure it to run interactively. Check [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-windows?view=azure-devops#choose-interactive-or-service-mode) for more information.

Or, You can pre-install the SqlServer module on your agent machine. Then you will be able to use the invoke-sqlcmd command in your pipeline.

You can also use microsoft-hosted agent to run your pipeline. invoke-sqlcmd command is available in agent `windows-2019` and `vs2017-win2016`